# What iOS api is used to put a colourful countdown timer in the Lock Screen notification area?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, widgetkit

When you have an active timer in the Apple clock app, it displays the countdown as a colourful interactive widget in the notifications area of the Lock Screen.

I know that it used to be the case that Apple's clock app used a private API to put a countdown on the lock screen, and third-party apps could not achieve the same result.

However I've just seen a parking app (RingGo) showing what looks like a custom-designed animated countdown interface on the Lock Screen. I didn't have to add it to my Lock Screen as I would a WidgetKit widget.

What API is RingGo using to do this?

Apple's native timer:

[image: Apple timer screenshot]

RingGo app:

[image: RingGo screenshot]

Comment: You have to build your own timer, but they are using Live Activities to display it https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/displaying-live-data-with-live-activities

Comment: Thanks! I'll put this in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the [Live Activity API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/displaying-live-data-with-live-activities).

Thanks to Andrew in the above comment for the info.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Text init:
`init(timerInterval: ClosedRange<Date>, pauseTime: Date? = nil, countsDown: Bool = true, showsHours: Bool = true)`

This will create the exact same timer you see for RingGo.