# How do I have my live activity update the seconds?

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit, activitykit

I want my live activity to update the seconds, but if the app is closed, the live activity doesn't update anymore:

[image]

I have seen live activities update seconds before, but it doesn't work for me.

Here is my code for my SwiftUI Button:

```
Button(
    action: {
        if isActivityGoing == false {
            let backgroundUIColor = UIColor(backgroundColor)
            
            var backgroundR: CGFloat = 0
            var backgroundG: CGFloat = 0
            var backgroundB: CGFloat = 0
            var backgroundAlpha: CGFloat = 0
            
            backgroundUIColor.getRed(&backgroundR, green: &backgroundG, blue: &backgroundB, alpha: &backgroundAlpha)
            
            let backgroundColorTable: [String: Double] = ["R": backgroundR, "G": backgroundG, "B": backgroundB]
            
            let textUIColor = UIColor(textColor)
            var textR: CGFloat = 0
            var textG: CGFloat = 0
            var textB: CGFloat = 0
            var textAlpha: CGFloat = 0
            
            textUIColor.getRed(&textR, green: &textG, blue: &textB, alpha: &textAlpha)
            
            let textColorTable: [String: Double] = ["R": textR, "G": textG, "B": textG]
            
            let activityAttributes = Seconds_Attributes(
                backgroundColor: backgroundColorTable,
                textColor: textColorTable
            )
            
            let timeSeconds: Int = Calendar.current.component(.second, from: Date())
            
            let contentState = Seconds_Attributes.ContentState(seconds: timeSeconds)
            
            let activityContent = ActivityContent(
                state: contentState,
                staleDate: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 24, to: Date())!)
            
            do {
                activity = try Activity.request(
                    attributes: activityAttributes,
                    content: activityContent)
                isActivityGoing = true
            } catch (let error) {
                print("Error occured: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                isActivityGoing = false
            }
            
            Task(priority: TaskPriority.background) {
                while isActivityGoing == true {
                    sleep(1)
                    
                    let updatedContent = Seconds_Attributes.TimeSeconds(seconds: Calendar.current.component(.second, from: Date()))
                    
                    let activityContent = ActivityContent(
                        state: updatedContent,
                        staleDate: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 24, to: Date())!)
                    
                    await activity?.update(activityContent)
                }
            }
            
        } else {
            let finalContent = ActivityContent(state: Seconds_Attributes.ContentState(seconds: 0), staleDate: nil)
            Task {
                await activity?.end(finalContent, dismissalPolicy: .immediate)
                isActivityGoing = false
            }
        }
    },
```

I have tried setting the priority to background for the task, but that doesn't seem to work.

I am expecting the live activity to update every time the second of the time changes.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74616702/update-live-activity-once-per-second-swift

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer:

You should use one of these `SwiftUI` Views to let the system itself update the labels every second:

• `Text(date, style: .timer)`

• `Text(timerInterval: startDate...endDate)`

#### Longer answer:

Your code relies on actively executing some code (`while`-loop with `sleep()` function). While this might work while your app is in foreground (and even some time in background if you enable some Capabilities), when you shut down the app the code you want to execute cannot run since the process is killed.

To run something when the app is closed you should use `backgroundTask` but this isn't suitable in this case either.

Generally there's currently no way to update anything except for the time with above-mentioned `Text`s in the live activity from background or when the app is closed except for Push Notifications and for that you'd need a server